# How to customise bootstrap horizontal form theme/template in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twig, symfony

I am working on an application built using Symfony 3. I am using the '[bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig)' form theme that came with the framework.

I have imported it successfully.

I tried to change the default column sizes; http://pastebin.com/7QvEQyVi but doesn't seem to have any effect.

The default sizes are 2 and 10 for the labels and input columns respectively. How can I override these values?

Appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by placing the modified block in a separate file as per @jkuchravic's answer;

app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig

```
{% use 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_label_class -%}
col-sm-3
{%- endblock form_label_class %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
col-sm-9
{%- endblock form_group_class %}
```

I didn't want to make the change application-wide so just applied the modified template to that particular form using the following line:

```
{% form_theme form with ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig','form/fields.html.twig'] %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can override it in your own template

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    form_themes:
        - "form/fields.html.twig"
```

<kbd>app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% use 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_label_class -%}
col-sm-3
{%- endblock form_label_class %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
col-sm-9
{%- endblock form_group_class %}
```

Comment: I couldn't get it working following this method. From what I understand, this would override the template globally which isn't what I want.